# VS2010: Right mouse clicked "Open in Expression Blend": Unsupported project

Tags: silverlight, expression-blend, visual-studio-2010

I am running VS2010 and have Expression Blend 3 installed.

I select a file, MainPage.xaml and select the option "Open in Expression Blend."

Expression Blend 3 is opened and my associated web application "SilverApplication1.Web" is displayed in the project explorer with the error "Unsupported project."

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must be using Silverlight 4. Try downgrading to 3. Not sure if Expression Blend supports 4 yet. You may try the pre release beta of Expression 4.

Answer (score 2):

Expression Blend 4 is required to understand VS2010 projects.  Blend 3 does not.  You may be eligible for a Blend 4 upgrade (if your Blend 3 is a part of a Studio installation).  Details:

> With this release comes a free Upgrade
>   for licensed version 3 (Studio or Web)
>   users!  All you need to do is install
>   the trial version of v4 on top of your
>   licensed version of Expression Studio
>   3 or Expression Web 3 and the
>   installer will find your license and
>   upgrade it to the full v4 product with
>   no expiration.  This applies to
>   customers who received their software
>   through retail channels or electronic
>   software download direct.  For
>   customers who have broader license
>   agreements (i.e., MSDN, WebsiteSpark,
>   BizSpark) you should install the
>   product using the software provided
>   from your program site.